# Does the example route in the api.php do anything?

Tags: php, laravel

Because of this bug in laravel: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22034

```
Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.
```

I wonder if the example route in api.php does anything or is it safe to just remove it?

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Comment: I don't think its meant to do anything apart from showing the developer an example of how to create an api route, with middleware and that a user is already authenticated if it returns a user response. So its safe to remove it and use your own routes.

Comment: Thank you! Please write this as answer so I can mark as correct